# Error in MYSQL when using multiple 'and' statements

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve outputs with multiple 'and' statements. My code works fine until i add a particular 'and' statement.

This is the code that i am using

```
select OC.CUSTOMER_ID,OC.CUSTOMER_FNAME,OC.CUSTOMER_LNAME,OH.PAYMENT_MODE,OH.ORDER_ID,SUM(OI.PRODUCT_QUANTITY) AS PRODUCT_QUANTITY,OH.ORDER_STATUS
FROM online_customer AS OC JOIN order_header AS OH
ON OC.CUSTOMER_ID=OH.CUSTOMER_ID
JOIN order_items AS OI
ON OH.ORDER_ID=OI.ORDER_ID
WHERE OH.ORDER_STATUS LIKE '%Shipped%'AND
OH.PAYMENT_MODE LIKE '%CREDIT CARD%' AND OH.PAYMENT_MODE LIKE '%NET BANKING%' AND
OH.ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDER_ITEMS GROUP BY ORDER_ID HAVING SUM(PRODUCT_QUANTITY)>10) 
GROUP BY ORDER_ID;
```

The issue pop's up when i add this particular line
`OH.PAYMENT_MODE LIKE '%CREDIT CARD%' AND OH.PAYMENT_MODE LIKE '%NET BANKING%'`
when i add this line only the table heads are derived [output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkpqW.png).
But when i remove that statement the output work's fine [output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge6Ja.png).

Comment: This means that there are no rows in the table containing both `'CREDIT CARD'` and  `'NET BANKING'` in the column `OH.PAYMENT_MODE`. Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: no actually  there are a lot of payment modes in the column payment mode such as cash, credit card, net banking etc. Among them i only need those rows which have payment mode =credit card  and net banking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"AND" means "both of these conditions have to be true *for the same row*".

There is no row where `OH.PAYMENT_MODE` contains both 'CREDIT CARD' *and* 'NET BANKING' so the condition is not true for any rows.

You want to look for rows where *either* of the conditions is true, so need an "OR". However, always be careful mixing "AND" and "OR"; the best idea is to use brackets, so `... AND ( OH.PAYMENT_MODE LIKE '%CREDIT CARD%' OR OH.PAYMENT_MODE LIKE '%NET BANKING%' ) AND ...`